# how to delete whitespace from nd array python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have yearly data sets with some missing data. I used this code to read but unable to omit white space present at the end of february. can anyone help to solve this problem?

```
df1 = pd.read_fwf('DQ404.7_77.txt',widths=ws,header=9, nrows=31, keep_default_na = False)
df1 = df1.drop('Day', 1)
df2 = np.array(df1).T
```

what I want is to arrange all the data in one column with respect to date. My data is uploaded in this link you can download
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2rkXkOkG7ExbEVwZUpHR29LNFE

what i wanted is to get time series data from this file and it should be like

```
Feb,25  13
Feb,26  13
Feb,27  13
Feb,28  13
March, 1    10
March, 2    10
March, 3    10
```

Not with empty strings in between february and March

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to remove rows where the entries are `NaN` or empty strings `''`?

Comment: You've not included the definition for `ws` so your code is not runnable

Comment: @ EdChum no no I have defination of ws, and wanted to remove empty strings . and I have defined ws  = [4,9,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]

Comment: So you want to drop the rows or replace empty strings with `NaN`?

Comment: hello EdChum, I want to drop empty strings, so that when I stack it should be regular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of comments it looks like `df[df != '']` works for you

Comment: then we will miss the values from Jan and from other month...isn't it?

Comment: I asked you what you wanted you stated `I want to drop empty strings, so that when I stack it should be regular` dropping doesn't equal replacement so you've not explained clear enough what you want. So I ask again what do you want instead of empty strings? Do you want `NaN` or you want to forward fill from the last valid value?

Comment: sorry for not making it clear but , I want to forward fill from the last valid value

Comment: What about the other `'NA'` values do you want these to be treated as `NaN` and forward filled?

Comment: for other 'NA' values, I want to keep it as NaN :).

Comment: @ EdChum, but still in your edited answer, now we have 31 data for february, which is not a case

Comment: Jesus can you state your problem clearer, I asked what you wanted you first said dropped, you then said you wanted them to be forward filled, so what was wrong with my first answer `df[df['Feb.' != '']`?

Comment: @bikuser - I think the best is add to question what is exactly your desired output. Then `EdChum` can help you.

Comment: clearly what i wanted is to make good time series data from this file right? for that i tried to read by this code but the problem was it has some empty string at the end of Feb and also in other months. so simply I want to remove only empty strings from the data.

Comment: So I ask again what was wrong with `df[df['Feb.' != '']`? or `df[df != '']`? and no it was not clear

Comment: df[df != ''] works :). Thank you @EdChum for your support.